# Phyton| After Compiling to exe it doesnt start the threads and just restarts

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, bots, sneakers

I got this:

```
if question2 == "1":
        print(Fore.YELLOW + 'Starting....')
        time.sleep(2)
        print(Fore.GREEN + 'Started Task [1]!')
        system("title " + f"Converse Bot V.1.0 User: {user} [Running Task[1]]")
        p1 = Process(target=atc)
        p1.start()
```

question 2 is a normal input where you can enter 1 or 2
after entering 1 it should print this and start the thread
in python file it works fine but after compiling to exe it just goes to " system("title " + f"Converse Bot V.1.0 User: {user} [Running Task[1]]")" that step and then restarts with the first step ( Saying Hello )

Please help me

Comment: What is `Process`?  What do you do after this returns?  You aren't waiting for the thread, so if this flows off the end of the program, the app will end and the thread will be aborted.

Comment: if possibly, do you think you could post the surrounding code for a little more context?